# When to use a covering index, a composite index, and unique columnar indexes

Tags: sql-server, database-design, indexing, rdbms

Let's say I have the following table in SQL Server 2008:

```
ProfileID   int          //identity; index: unique, primary key, clustered
ClientID    int
RegionID    int
ProfileName nvarchar(50)
```

Columns 2 and 3 link to their respective tables via foreign relationships.

Let's say my most common query is this:

```
SELECT ProfileID, ProfileName
FROM   Profiles
WHERE  ClientID = ? AND RegionID = ?
ORDER  BY ProfileName
```

What indexing system is best suited?

If I put a covering index on (ProfileID, ProfileName), then that kills the default clustered index since covering indexes have to be non-clustered, but satisfies at least the return part of the query.

If I leave the primary key as-is, and independently index ClientID and RegionID, that gives me 3 indexes that have to be maintained by the RDBMS, PLUS a table scan would still be needed to return ProfileName as it isn't covered. This seems heavy.

A simple case-study of how intricate indexing planning can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT  ProfileID, ProfileName
FROM    Profiles
WHERE   ClientID = ? AND RegionID = ?
ORDER BY
        ProfileName
```

you should create this index:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_profiles_region_client_name ON (RegionID, ClientID, ProfileName)
```

Within a single value of `(RegionID, ClientID)`, the records are sorted on `ProfileName`, so that the records will go sorted and no additional sorting will be needed.

Since `ProfileID` is a `PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED`, it is implicitly included into each index record, so there is no need to specify it in the index definition explicitly.

If it were not a clustered key, you would need to add it to the index for it to cover this query:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_profiles_region_client_name__id ON (RegionID, ClientID, ProfileName) INCLUDE (ProfileID)
```

Comment: @Quassnoi my friend, you are back. I assume you mean "... and leave the primary index too"? Not just this one index?

Comment: Quassnoi I have two questions: 1) I would have thought (ClientID, RegionID...) would be better since ClientID is the most unique column (ok, I didn't mention that in my question, granted). I take it the order is most unique to least unique.
The second Q is why is ProfileName in the index, but not as an included column, when we're not specifically querying it?

Comment: @Ianc: for this very query it does not matter much since the search is always performed on the whole tuple `(ClientID, RegionID)`. However, you may swap the order if you need to search on `ClientID` alone (or in combination with columns other than `RegionID`). `ProfileName` is in the index because it's used in the `ORDER BY` clause. Included columns are not sorted by the index and the query hence would need to sort if you included `ProfileName` as a non-key column.

Comment: @Quassnoi Thanks. One final question, if you don't mind. If I needed to search often against either ClientID or RegionID, would the index you gave still be optimum?

Comment: @IanC: two separate indexes would be best: `(ClientID, RegionID)` and `RegionID`

Comment: @Quassnoi ok, so we would get these 2 (excl. the obvious primary):

CREATE INDEX ix_profiles_region_client_name ON (RegionID, ClientID, ProfileName)

CREATE INDEX ix_profiles_client_region ON (ClientID, RegionID)

Comment: @IanC: There is no need to add `RegionID` into the second one. Queries on `(ClientID, RegionID)` will be served by the first one.